# How do I fit the Weibull distribution to my dataset?

Tags: statistics, julia, weibull, function-fitting, dataframes.jl

I'm looking to fit a vector of Floats to the Weibull distribution using the `fit()` function from  Distributions.jl . The error I get is:

```
ERROR: DomainError with NaN:
Weibull: the condition α > zero(α) is not satisfied.
```

I've been able to do it for all the continuous distributions in their `applicable distributions` section https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/fit/#Applicable-distributions ,

but can't seem to get it to work for the Weibull. My syntax is:

```
fit_mle(Weibull, nice[:,1])
```

For reproducibility, here's the data I was using:  https://ufile.io/ticx73py

Thanks in advance! All responders are awesome!

Comment: Can you please provide a definition for `nice`? The error message suggests the problem is that `nice` contains NaNs, zeros, negative numbers, or something that can't be fit using `fit_mle`. `fit_mle(Weibull, rand(10))` works for me.

Comment: To add support to my hypothesis that `nice` is the problem, `fit_mle(Weibull, vcat(rand(10), [NaN]))` reproduces your error.

Comment: @PaSTE I think you're right! I found that transforming it to become all positive makes it work just fine.